# Pandas to Compare two dataframes row wise with indexed columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have a Two CSVs with same column names, i want to get row-wise difference to write it in a CSV file path.

I have also indexed the "ID" column in both the files/Dataframes.

**Sample Dataframes**

```
data1 = {
    'ID': [100, 21, 32, 42, 51, 81],
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F'],
    'State': [TX, FL, FL, CA, CA, TX ]
}
data2 = {
    'ID': [100, 21, 32, 42, 51, 81],
    'Name': ['A', 'BB', 'C', 'DD','E','F'],  # Difference in the 2nd,4th row
    'State': [TX, TX, FL, CA, CA, TX]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Indexed by 'ID'

df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')
```

My logic is giving me a boolean error. I have multiple logic which doesnt seem to work.

**METHOD - 1**

```
# Find common indices between DataFrames
common_index = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)

# Save differences to an output file
output_file_path = 'row_wise_differences.txt'
with open(output_file_path, 'w') as file:
    for idx in common_index:
        differences = []
        for col in df1.columns:
            if df1.loc[idx, col] != df2.loc[idx, col]:
                differences.append(f"{col}: {df1.loc[idx, col]} <> {df2.loc[idx, col]}")
        if differences:
            file.write(f"Index ID: {idx}, Differences: {', '.join(differences)}\n")
        else:
            file.write(f"Index ID: {idx}, No Differences\n")

print(f"Differences saved to {output_file_path}")
```

**METHOD-2**

```
common_index = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)

# Save differences to an output file
output_file_path = 'row_wise_differences.txt'
with open(output_file_path, 'w') as file:
    for idx in common_index:
        differences = [f"{col}: {df1.loc[idx, col]} <> {df2.loc[idx, col]}" for col in df1.columns if df1.loc[idx, col] != df2.loc[idx, col]]
        if differences:
            file.write(f"Index ID: {idx}, Differences: {', '.join(differences)}\n")
        else:
            file.write(f"Index ID: {idx}, No Differences\n")

print(f"Differences saved to {output_file_path}")
```

**Method-3**

```
# Create a DataFrame showing differences as 'ID: Column: Value1 <> Value2'
diff_df = df1.loc[common_index][differences].stack().reset_index()
diff_df.columns = ['ID', 'Column', 'Difference']
diff_df['Difference'] = diff_df['Column'] + ': ' + diff_df['Difference'].astype(str)

# Save differences to an output CSV file
output_file_path = 'row_wise_differences.csv'
diff_df.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False)

print(f"Differences saved to {output_file_path}")
```

**Expected output**
Indexed ID: 21, Difference: Name: B <> BB, State: FL <> TX
Indexed ID: 42, Difference: Name: D <> DD, State: CA <> CA

Output format does not matter as long as the df1 & df2 names and row wise difference is captured.

Please help me with the comparision logic.
I am running into the below mentioned error for all my logics

```
ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambiguous, Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Thanks in advance for all the time taken to help me out!

Comment: Many problems here 1) None of these codes produce the error you describe. 2) There are errors in the codes that means they do not compile - please fix the compile errors so your examples will run. 3) Why do you expect this "difference"  `State: CA <> CA`

Comment: @topsail I just wanted to capture the other columns even when there is one difference found per row.

Comment: will both df rows and column 'ID'  same always?

Comment: @Venkat
 Both the Dfs have different shape however, the number of columns remain same even for the ID as ID is unique and indexed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not get the error you describe at all, but from your comments it seems the only really problem is that you need to get all the columns in your output.

You can accomplish this with a little added logic to make sure you get all the column values in your output.

But since I think it is possibly easier to compare two dataframes using `compare`, I also give an example of this as an alternative solution.

#### Setup data

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'ID': [100, 21, 32, 42, 51, 81],
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F'],
    'State': ['TX', 'FL', 'FL', 'CA', 'CA', 'TX' ]
}
data2 = {
    'ID': [100, 21, 32, 42, 51, 81],
    'Name': ['A', 'BB', 'C', 'DD','E','F'],  # Difference in the 2nd,4th row
    'State': ['TX', 'TX', 'FL', 'CA', 'CA', 'TX']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1).set_index("ID")
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2).set_index("ID")
```

#### Solution with code fix to method 1

```
# Find common indices between DataFrames
common_index = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)

# Save differences to an output file
found = False
output_file_path = 'row_wise_differences.txt'
with open(output_file_path, 'w') as file:
    for idx in common_index:
        differences = []
        found = False
        for col in df1.columns:
            if df1.loc[idx, col] != df2.loc[idx, col]:
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            for col in df1.columns:
                differences.append(f"{col}: {df1.loc[idx, col]}/{df2.loc[idx, col]}")
            file.write(f"Index ID: {idx}, Differences: {', '.join(differences)}\n")
        else:
            file.write(f"Index ID: {idx}, No Differences\n")
print(f"Differences saved to {output_file_path}")
```

#### Alternate solution using `df.compare()`

```
# find differences
result = df1.compare(df2, align_axis=1, keep_equal=True, result_names=('DF1', 'DF2'))

# flatten multi-column index (optional)
result.columns =  [f'{col[1]}-{col[0]}' for col in result.columns.values]

# output differences report (optional - could also simply export as a csv file)
with open('differences.txt', 'w') as file:
    for t in result.itertuples():
        file.write(f'ID: {t[0]} Name: {t[1]}/{t[2]} State: {t[3]}/{t[4]}\n')
```

Comment: Hi @topsail - I am still getting the boolean value Error mentioned in the question.

Comment: your code worked well without indexing

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful to u. No need to reindex the df.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

diff_rows = df1[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Hi @Venkat - this is not helping in clearly visualizing the output for validation

Comment: you want answer in same format which have u mentioned above

Comment: just want to output and capture row wise comparison details